# PHP: Quote within a quote within a quote

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to put a quote within a quote within a quote in PHP. I've looked around in other answers on this site, but none work with the issue I'm trying to solve.

I'm trying to run a shell_exec command for a python script that takes some arguments, which need to be in the form of strings. The problem with this is that it requires there to be a string within a string within another string, and all methods I've tried so far cause this not to work. 
I can work my script through the terminal , so I am 100% sure there's nothing wrong with the python script.

Any help on how to accomplish this would be helpful. Here is the command so far:

```
$command = "/home/xxxx/.local/bin/python3 -c 'from test import hmm; hmm($o1, $o2, $o3)'";
```

Comment: A copule of things to try. Reverse the quotes, that is use `'/home... -c "from ..."';` and maybe escape a double quote instead of using a single quote. eg. `"/home... -c \"from ...\"";`

Comment: What do you mean by "a string within a string within another string"? I see only 2 strings in your variable.

Answer (score -1):

You should utilise [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function. You code should look something like this:

```
$o1 = escapeshellarg($o1);
$o2 = escapeshellarg($o2);
$o3 = escapeshellarg($o3);
$arg = "from test import hmm; hmm($o1, $o2, $o3)";
$arg = escapeshellarg($arg);
$command = "/home/xxxx/.local/bin/python3 -c $arg";
```

Your output will look messy, but shell will properly execute it.